# postgresql поиск в uuid поле по части строки

Tags: postgresql

Не пойму как реализовать в postgresql сабж. Со строкой все ясно

```
SELECT object_name FROM _object WHERE object_name ILIKE '%отр%'
```

но эта тема не работает с uuid который требует корректный синтаксис

```
SELECT object_name FROM _object WHERE oid ILIKE '%bb1%'    
ОШИБКА:  неверный синтаксис для типа uuid: "%bb1%"
```

подскажите плиз, как реализовать

Comment: приведите его к строковому типу. что то вроде `oid::varchar`

Comment: отлично! спасибо!